# Google Sheets <> Coinmarket cap API dynamic sheet

Tags: google-apps-script, google-sheets, coinmarketcap

)

What I would like to do is extend this piece of code to make it less hard coded but dynamic. It maybe easier to hard code the coinmarketcap api key.

I would like to do the following in google sheets (its not allowing me to pass argument in function and debug it so I dont know what is happening, its coming back undefined)

| name | price |
| --- | --- |
| BTC | 41665 |
| ADA | 1.9 |

I would like to pass the name of the coin and return the price, so the function would be =getcryptoprice(name)

Any help would be greatly appreciated.

```
function getCryptoPrice() {
  var sh1=SpreadsheetApp.getActiveSpreadsheet().getSheetByName("Prices[DontDelete]");
  var sh2=SpreadsheetApp.getActiveSpreadsheet().getSheetByName("Prices[DontDelete]");
  
  //Make sure that you got the API key from Coinmarketcap API dashboard and paste it in sheet_1 on cell A1
  var apiKey=sh1.getRange(1, 1).getValue();
  
  var url="https://pro-api.coinmarketcap.com/v1/cryptocurrency/quotes/latest?symbol=BTC" 
  var requestOptions = {
  method: 'GET',
  uri: 'https://pro-api.coinmarketcap.com/v1/cryptocurrency/listings/latest',
  qs: {
    start: 1,
    limit: 5000,
    convert: 'USD'
  },
  headers: {
    'X-CMC_PRO_API_KEY': apiKey
  },
  json: true,
  gzip: true
};
  
  var httpRequest= UrlFetchApp.fetch(url, requestOptions);
  var getContext= httpRequest.getContentText();
  
  var parseData=JSON.parse(getContext);
  sh2.getRange(1, 2).setValue(parseData.data.BTC.quote.USD.price)
```

Answer (score 1):

You can change `parseData.data.BTC.quote.USD.price` to `parseData.data[code].quote.USD.price` with code = BTC

Try this : `=getCryptoPrice("BTC")`

```
function getCryptoPrice(code) {
  var sh1 = SpreadsheetApp.getActiveSpreadsheet().getSheetByName("Prices[DontDelete]");
  var sh2 = SpreadsheetApp.getActiveSpreadsheet().getSheetByName("Prices[DontDelete]");

  //Make sure that you got the API key from Coinmarketcap API dashboard and paste it in sheet_1 on cell A1
  var apiKey = sh1.getRange(1, 1).getValue();

  var url = "https://pro-api.coinmarketcap.com/v1/cryptocurrency/quotes/latest?symbol="+code
  var requestOptions = {
    method: 'GET',
    uri: 'https://pro-api.coinmarketcap.com/v1/cryptocurrency/listings/latest',
    qs: {
      start: 1,
      limit: 5000,
      convert: 'USD'
    },
    headers: {
      'X-CMC_PRO_API_KEY': apiKey
    },
    json: true,
    gzip: true
  };

  var httpRequest = UrlFetchApp.fetch(url, requestOptions);
  var getContext = httpRequest.getContentText();

  var parseData = JSON.parse(getContext);
  return(parseData.data[code].quote.USD.price)

}
```

### edit : to refresh

**method #1**
you can refresh values by adding a dummy parameter as a checkbox in A1 for instance and include in the second argument of the function as `=getCryptoPrice("BTC",$A$1)`

then, define a trigger (each hour) in this custom function

```
function refresh(){
  var chk = SpreadsheetApp.getActiveSpreadsheet().getSheetByName('Sheet1').getRange('A1')
  chk.setValue(!chk.getValue())
}
```

**method #2**
same formula `=getCryptoPrice("BTC",$A$1)` with `=now()` in A1. Then go to settings for the spreadsheet, calculation tab, choose recalculation on change and every hour

Comment: almost, I think the
```
var url = "https://pro-api.coinmarketcap.com/v1/cryptocurrency/quotes/latest?symbol=BTC"
```

Think I need to make this url dynamic at the end. I believe it is pointing to BTC

Comment: yes, you are right, i have amended my answer with var `url = "https://pro-api.coinmarketcap.com/v1/cryptocurrency/quotes/latest?symbol="+code`

Comment: Mike would you know how to restrict calls to the api to once per hour? or would that have to be handled outside of google sheets

Comment: How do you call the function? by a formula `=getCryptoPrice("BTC")` inside the sheet or by another function in script?

Comment: I have posted a method to refresh. Others exist with javascript in sidebar.

Comment: I call the formula by =getCryptoPrice("BTC", "USD"). im trying to implement what you have done above

Comment: =getCryptoPrice("BTC",$A$1) with =now(), this method makes more sense but I get an #error (#ERROR! this function is not allowed to reference a cell with NOW(), RAND(), or RANDBETWEEN())  as my formula is =getCryptoPrice("BTC", "USD", $A$2) with =now().... Do i also need to extend the function =getCryptoPrce to include the dummy variable

Comment: in the script, remove money: `function getCryptoPrice(code)` then apply method#1 instead (this limitation seems to be new)